# Is there anything like a "Tikun Korim" for Nach?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, jewish-books, torah-reading

Is there a printed text like a תיקון קוראים for learning נ"ך, where one side has the כתיב without נקודות or טעמים?

Comment: Never seen one. However some of the Tikun L'Korims have the weekly Haftaros in them too.

Comment: Yes, my Tikun has that. I was wondering about the whole of Nach though.

Comment: You can make Tikkunei Korim (?) for any part of Tanach at [this website](http://www.lashon.net/CL/Tanach/Tikkun.cgi).

Comment: Simanim has one for the 5 Megilot - http://www.darga.org.il/product.asp?productid=1754

Comment: What is the need for the entire Nach as a Tikkun?

Comment: @BackseatChazan I'd like to one wait know how to memorize the laining the whole of Tanach, as was done in days of yore. Not for any communal reason but for my personal talmud torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA That sounds like an answer, to me....

Comment: @Shokhet It's not printed

Comment: @DoubleAA, I tried them before asking my Eicha question and they seemed like low quality tikkunim to me.

Answer (score 3):

The Zilberman Cheder in the Old City of Yerushalayim printed a seperate volume for each Neviim and Kesuvim without any trop or nekudos.