# Online Tikkun Makers?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, torah-reading

Are there any resources online that one can use to make tikkun readers for people that can be easily accessed online or that can be used to generate PDFs for printing?

Having a Tikkun book is not preferable as i will be the coordinator for Torah readers, and it may fall to me to create Tikkuns for individual readers, some of which may not be technically inclined. So PDFs or online generators would work best. Some of these answers are already helpful, but none of them perfect yet.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34614/is-there-anything-like-a-tikun-korim-for-nach#comment89484_34614

Answer (score 7):

Try https://www.tikkun.io.

**Full disclosure**: I'm the creator of this site. As a software developer and avid Torah reader, I found nothing online that I enjoyed using and that was free. This one will be free forever.

Comment: you're a legend. Thank you! Super useful!

Comment: What text of Tanakh did you use?

Comment: @DoubleAA [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org) has various sources available on Github

Comment: @akiva ok but note sefarias text differs from "standard" in a few places

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks for letting me know – I have found some really minor differences in trop, and I have updated my copy of the source in some of the places. If you find others, please don't hesitate to let me know any differences by either commenting here, opening an issue, or submitting a pull request – thanks!

Comment: Don't correct the trop. For trop the sefaria version is usually better. For vowels and spelling, "common editions" are probably better so change those. It's best to just say somewhere on your site what text you are using. That way people know what they are getting. If you made any changes best to document that somewhere.

Comment: For instance, in Gen 8:20 you have הטהורה but my Torah scroll has הטהרה.

Comment: If you aren't interested in designing your own text, the best one out there free on the internet is [this one](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A9:Dovi/%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94#%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9) licensed CC-BY-SA, though I don't know what formats you can readily download it in.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for the feedback and suggestions! I'll take look and see what I can do.

Comment: Also, another thing to consider is adapting your code to the rest of nach to answer https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34614/759

Comment: How did you program this? Looks like just Javascript, but you use JSX. You don't use React?

Comment: @robev – it's just regular JavaScript, no React or JSX. I love React, I just didn't use it for this project, although that might change one day. You may be confusing the template strings that output HTML as JSX, but it's just regular HTML syntax.

Answer (score 3):

How about [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/50656) from Hebrew Books.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of sites you might find useful.

http://www.lashon.net/CL/Tanach/Tikkun.cgi

http://scrollscraper.adatshalom.net/

Answer (score 1):

I've used [this one](http://www.beverlyhillschabad.com/torah-reading/TORAH-MENU.HTM) from Beverly Hills Chabad and it's superb.