# Tikkun Sofrim for Nach

Tags: safrus, navi-prophets, haftarah

Is there a mainstream (or popular) Tikkun Sofrim used for the layout of complete Sifrei Nevi’im (and K’suvim)?

Notes: In the recent years, there seems to be a great uniformity in the way sofrim write Sifrei Torah (e.g. 42 lines, vavei ha’amudim etc) due to the standardization of the Tikkunim (particularly the infuence of R’ Davidovich).

There also seems to be a growing minhag to read haftarah from complete books of Navi written in the same way as a Sefer Torah (on a klaf scroll by a sofer). Is there a (more or less) standard Tikkun Sofrim used to write these complete Sifrei Nach?

Comment: You might find the second part of [this video](https://youtu.be/ahj_xz5H9J8) by Prof. Ofer interesting

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34614/759

Comment: Maybe. My question was more about the standardized layout used by sofrim (for example, for Shiras Devorah while writing a complete Sefer Shoftim).

Comment: @DoubleAA Based on the recent edit I disagree.

Comment: There's the "Berdechiv Tikkun", but it's riddled with errors and you're better off using the newer ones that are made accurately

Comment: Does the Berdichev Tikkun have any parts of Nach besides the 5 megillos? Those can be founds in many new Tikkunim. My question was more about Sifrei Navi that are read from complete scrolls in a growing number of places (shuls and yeshivos), based on the GRA.